# maven & IntelliJ IDEA & no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Нашёл в google не десяток аналогичных вопросов, и везде (практически) советуют одно и тоже - добавить код ниже в **pom.xml**:

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.petersamokhin.Main</mainClass>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```

Однако, не у одного меня IDEA выдаёт ошибку - `Element archive is not allowed here`, и в результате всё равно `no main manifest attribute`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема и как лечить? mvn установлен, во время компиляции ошибок тоже нет.

Comment: Компилятор не имеет никакого отношения к манифестам, естественно такая конфигурация не имеет смысла и не будет работать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Добавил ещё один тег **plugin**:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.mypackage.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Полностью теперь тег **build** выглядит так:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mypackage.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Затем:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```